# How to make exoplayer play media from a list of songs

Tags: android, kotlin, media, exoplayer

I am building a music player app.

In there, there are various segments:

1. All Songs - All songs from a user device
2. Playlist - All songs a user has added to playlist
3. Favourites - Songs a user has added as favorites/liked
4. Artistes Songs - All songs from an artiste

Right now, I have set up everything and I can play "ALL" songs etc...

**What I want**

When the user is in:

**Playlist** - Play only list of songs in that playlist

**Favorites** - Play only list of songs in favorites

**Artiste Songs** - Play only list of songs from an artiste

I have the list of songs from various segments

Right now, I can only play ALL songs from user media...So, the queue is from **ALL  SONGS IN THE DEVICE**.. Which I dont want.

I have no problem with **ALL SONGS** Segment...

Example

**FavoriteSongsFragment**

```
private var allSongs: List<Songs>? = null
roomFavSongViewModel.getAllFavSongs.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { songs ->
allSongs = songs .....//Now I have a list of songs a user has marked as favorite...Is there a way I can add this as the queue for exoplayer to play only this list of songs, instead of all songs from media
}

favouriteSongsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {        
mainViewModel.playOrToggleSong(it)..//On click of a song from the list of song        
    }
```

**MainViewModel**

```
 class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
 private val musicServiceConnection: MusicServiceConnection,
 ) : ViewModel() {

 private val _mediaItems = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Songs>>>()
 val mediaItems: LiveData<Resource<List<Songs>>> = _mediaItems

val isConnected = musicServiceConnection.isConnected
val networkError = musicServiceConnection.networkError
val currentlyPlayingSong = musicServiceConnection.currentPlayingSong
val playBackState = musicServiceConnection.playbackState


init {

    _mediaItems.postValue(Resource.loading(null))

        musicServiceConnection.subscribe(

            MEDIA_ROOT_ID,
            object : MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback() {

                override fun onChildrenLoaded(
                    parentId: String,
                    children: MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>
                ) {
                    super.onChildrenLoaded(parentId, children)
                    val items = children.map {

                        val album = it.description.extras?.get("album")
                        val duration = it.description.extras?.get("duration")
                        val size = it.description.extras?.get("size")
                        val dateAdded = it.description.extras?.get("dateAdded")

                        Songs(
                            mediaId = it.mediaId?.toLong(),
                            title = it.description.title as String?,
                            subtitle = it.description.subtitle as String?,
                            songUri = it.description.mediaUri,
                            albumArtUri = it.description.iconUri,
                            duration = duration as Long?,
                            album = album as String?,
                            size = size as Long?,
                            dateAdded = dateAdded as String?
                        )
                    }
                    _mediaItems.value = Resource.success(items)
                }
            })
}

fun skipToNextSong(){
    musicServiceConnection.transportControls.skipToNext()
}

fun setShuffle(){
    musicServiceConnection.transportControls.setShuffleMode(PlaybackStateCompat.SHUFFLE_MODE_ALL)
}

fun offShuffle(){
    musicServiceConnection.transportControls.setShuffleMode(PlaybackStateCompat.SHUFFLE_MODE_NONE)
}

fun setRepeat(){
    musicServiceConnection.transportControls.setRepeatMode(PlaybackStateCompat.REPEAT_MODE_ONE)
}

fun offRepeat(){
    musicServiceConnection.transportControls.setRepeatMode(PlaybackStateCompat.REPEAT_MODE_NONE)
}

fun skipToPreviousSong(){
    musicServiceConnection.transportControls.skipToPrevious()
}

fun seekTo(pos: Long){
    musicServiceConnection.transportControls.seekTo(pos)
}

fun playOrToggleSong(
    mediaItem: Songs, toggle: Boolean = false
){
    val isPrepared = playBackState.value?.isPrepared ?: false

    if (isPrepared && mediaItem.mediaId.toString() ==
        currentlyPlayingSong.value?.getString(METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID)){
        playBackState.value?.let { playbackState ->

            when{
                playbackState.isPlaying -> if (toggle) musicServiceConnection.transportControls.pause()
                playbackState.isPlayEnabled -> musicServiceConnection.transportControls.play()
                else -> Unit
            }
        }
    }
    else{
       musicServiceConnection.transportControls.playFromMediaId(
           mediaItem.mediaId.toString(),
           null
       )
    }

}

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    musicServiceConnection.unSubscribe(
        MEDIA_ROOT_ID,
        object : MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback() {
        })
 }
}
```

Is there a way to tell exoplayer to build its queue from a particular list of songs??

Comment: I think it's useful for you: https://exoplayer.dev/playlists.html